# Python pandas to calculate mean of datetime of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given an example table `df` as below, how to calculate mean date of `TIME1, TIME2, TIME3.`

```
df['AVG_TIME'] = df[['TIME1', 'TIME2', 'TIME3']].mean(axis=1)
```

This returns `NaN` values

```
ID  TIME1   TIME2   TIME3 
0   2018-07-11  2018-07-09  2018-07-12 
1   2018-07-12  2018-06-12  2018-07-15 
2   2018-07-13  2018-06-13  2018-08-03 
3   2019-09-11  2019-08-11  2019-09-01 
4   2019-09-12  2019-08-12  2019-09-15
```

Comment: Are your columns `datetime`?

Comment: how about converting datetime object to timestamps like (int64) and then calculating average ?

Comment: Super weird case where `mean` is defined for a Series of datetime64, but not a DataFrame. `df.apply(pd.Series.mean, axis=1)` is one way, though there's an apply :(. Probably simplest to do `df.astype('int64').mean(1).astype('datetime64[ns]')`

Comment: @ALollz tried your method with my real data, "TypeError: ('DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation mean', 'occurred at index 12')"

Comment: @user3280146 it works. I useed astype(np.int64).mean(axis=1), and then converted it back to datetime by pd.to_datetime function.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done as follows:

```py
import time
import datetime

import pandas as pd

# build the df
c = ['TIME1' ,  'TIME2' ,   'TIME3']
d = [['2018-07-11',  '2018-07-09', '2018-07-12'],
     ['2018-07-12',  '2018-06-12', '2018-07-15'], 
     ['2018-07-13',  '2018-06-13', '2018-08-03'], 
     ['2019-09-11',  '2019-08-11', '2019-09-01'],
     ['2019-09-12',  '2019-08-12', '2019-09-15']]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=c)


# conversion from dates to seconds since epoch (unix time)
def to_unix(s):
    return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())

# sum the seconds since epoch, calculate average, and convert back to readable date
averages = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    unix = [to_unix(i) for i in row]
    average = sum(unix) / len(unix)
    averages.append(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(average).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

df['averages'] = averages
```